# Publish to all suave websockets

Tags: suave

How can I broadcast an event to all websocket clients in the below code example:

```
let echo (ws : WebSocket) =
    fun cx -> socket {
        let loop = ref true
        while !loop do
            let! msg = ws.read();
            match msg with
            | (Text, data, true) ->
                let str = UTF8.toString data
                printfn "****** Received: %s" str
                do! ws.send Text data true
            | (Ping, _, _) ->
                do! ws.send Pong [||] true
            | (Close, _, _) ->
                do! ws.send Close [||] true
                loop := false
            | _ -> ()
    }

let start home port =
    let config =
        { defaultConfig with
            logger = Logging.Loggers.saneDefaultsFor Logging.LogLevel.Verbose
            bindings = [ (if port |> String.IsNullOrEmpty then
                            HttpBinding.mkSimple HTTP "127.0.0.1" 3000
                          else HttpBinding.mkSimple HTTP "0.0.0.0" (int32 port)) ]
            homeFolder = home |> Some }

    let app =
        choose
            [
                path "/echo" >=> handShake echo
                NOT_FOUND "Sorry there is nothing there"
            ]

    startWebServer config app
```

So, basically, I want to be able to send a message to the server websocket, and have that message echoed to all current websocket clients. The use case is that I have a file watcher that sends a message to the server websocket and a websocket client in the browser that will refresh the browser if a message is received.

I think I need to keep a list of clients, but I am not sure what the best approach would be using suave.

As an example, using express this is simple:

```
(function () {
    var debug = require('debug')('app:server');
    var app = require('express')();
    var ws = require('express-ws')(app);

    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;

    // enable cors
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        return next();
    });

    app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        debug('get route');
        res.send('hello');
        res.end();
    });

    app.ws('/', function (ws, req) {
        ws.on('message', function (msg) {
            debug('websocket message', msg);
        });
    });

    app.listen(PORT);
    debug('watch server started on port: ' + PORT);

    /// Broadcast the reload event to all clients.
    exports.reload = function () {
        ws.getWss().clients.forEach(function (client) {
            debug('*** broadcast reload message');
            client.send('reload');
        });
    };


}());
```